# Ctrl stops animated scroll midway while using react-scroll and disable-scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-scroll

I am currently working on a website that is going to be having scrolling disabled while using a subset of properties on disableScroll(npm package)

```
disableScroll.on(
        {},
        {
            authorizedInInputs: [32, 37, 38, 39, 40],
            disableKeys: true,
            disableScroll: false,
            disableWheel: true,
            keyboardKeys: [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
        }
    );
```

I have disableScroll as false since I want to animate scrolling via using react-scroll Links(another npm package)

Everything works fine but now I noticed that if while the scrolling is ongoing(I have a duration of a second) if I press the ctrl key it stops the scrolling. I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening. Is there a way to disable this feature or is this a bug?

I do want to keep my animated scroll feature(react-scroll smooth scrolling no)

Not sure if it helps but I have set the scrollbar width to zero in order to prevent the user from scrolling altogether.

PS: I don't think any of my code snippets are required but if so let me know and I'll update them here